# In System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "<Path to your WebDriver>"), what is meant by "Path to your WebDriver"?

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have this exception since I upgraded to 3.0 beta with Firefox.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property

Answer (score 8):

It seems now we need to manually download and set path to the driver executable for Mozilla Firefox also just like chromedriver.

Following is what you need to do:-

1. Go to http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/
2. Scroll down to "**Third Party Drivers, Bindings, and Plugins**" section on downloads page
3. Click on Mozilla GeckoDriver and download(zip) latest version v0.10.0 for your operating system.
4. Extract on your desired location i.e. c:\GeckoDriver\geckodriver.exe

Now you need to set system property and write following lines to initialize FireFoxDriver object:-

**System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\GeckoDriver\geckodriver.exe");**

**WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();**

**driver.get("http://seleniumhq.com");**

Thats it!

Comment: I'm using windows/Eclipse/Selenium --> Adding: System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\GeckoDriver\geckodriver.exe"); --> I get an error on this line saying: Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Comment: Resolved the problem if it helps someone using double backward slash: "C:\\GeckoDriver\\geckodriver.exe"

Comment: Make sure there are no spaces anywhere in the path.

Answer (score 3):

Try below code in JAVA,
and its working fine me

1. need to updated selenium and selenium drivers for java
2. updated firefox, firefox driver

### in below code "C:\\Drivers\\geckodriver.exe" is path of your webdriver

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class FirstTestCase {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //WebDriver driver =new FirefoxDriver();

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.syncfusion.com/");
         System.out.println("Successfully opened the website www.Syncfusion.com"); 
        try {
            Thread.sleep(4000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         driver.quit();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C://Program Files (x86)//geckodriver-v0.11.1-win64//geckodriver.exe");
String testurl = "http://www.seleniumhq.com";
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get(testurl);
```

Normally this happens when the FF version is above 45 and thats when we download gecko driver (https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases). After this unzip the contents of the folder and drag and drop the exe file of gecko driver to this folder (src/main/resources) if you have created a maven project.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Thanks mike .... i will henceforth..... i will get better since i am at a learning stage cheers

Answer (score 1):

We use System.setProperty to provide the path of chromedriver/iedriver etc. Below is the declaration of java.lang.System.setProperty() method:

**public static String setProperty(String key, String value)**

**key** : Name of the system property

**value**: Value of the system property

e.g.
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/test/resources/chromedriver.exe");

webdriver.chrome.driver : Chrome Driver (Name of system property)
src/test/resources/chromedriver.exe : Path of chromedriver (value of system property)

Usually, we encounter **IllegalArgumentException** when key is empty.

Answer (score 0):

public class WaitTestCase {
    WebDriver driver;

```
@Test ()    
public void TC_Wait(){

System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver.exe");

driver = new FirefoxDriver();


        driver.get("http:\\yahoo.com");

        driver.quit();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
package webdriver_Commands;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class FirefoxFacebook {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

      System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Driver\\geckodriver.exe");

      WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.get("https:\\www.google.com");
    }
}
```